# Origin header is not working in L5 Swagger - Laravel

Tags: laravel, swagger, http-headers

I am using "darkaonline/l5-swagger" version 8.0 laravel(v 8.12) package for api documentation. My PHP version is 8.0.2. I created api annotation for GET and POST request. The post request automatically send "Origin" header. The Get method is not sending "Origin" header by default.

Package link: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

I need two things for this:

1. I want to change the default value of "Origin" header of POST request
2. I want to add custom "Origin" header in GET request

Below is my sample POST request

```
/**
 * @OA\Post(
 * path="/auth/login",
 * summary="Login",
 * description="This api will be used for login of all roles",
 * operationId="authLogin",
 * tags={"auth"},
 * @OA\Parameter(
*    name="Origin",
*    in="header",
*    description="Origin",
*    required=true,
*    example="http://example.com",
*    schema={
*    "type"="string"
*    },
*    style="simple",
* ),
 * @OA\RequestBody(
 *    required=true,
 *    description="Pass user credentials",
 *    @OA\JsonContent(
 *       required={"email","password"},
 *       @OA\Property(property="email", type="string", format="email", example="user1@mail.com"),
 *       @OA\Property(property="password", type="string", format="password", example="PassWord12345"),
 *    ),
 * ),
 * @OA\Response(
 *    response=422,
 *    description="Wrong credentials response",
 *    @OA\JsonContent(
 *       @OA\Property(property="error",
 *                  type="object",
 *                      @OA\Property(property="message",
 *                          type="string",
 *                          example="Email required"
 *                      ),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="field",
 *                          type="string",
 *                          example="email"
 *                      )
 *                  ),
 *              ),
 *     ),
 * @OA\Response(
 *    response=200,
 *    description="Login success",
 *    @OA\JsonContent(
 *       @OA\Property(property="data",
 *                  type="object",
 *                      @OA\Property(property="status", type="boolean", example=true),
 *                  ),
 *          ),
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

Below is my sample GET request

```
/**
 * @OA\Get(
 * path="/school-courses",
 * summary="Get school courses",
 * description="This api will be used to get all course of school",
 * operationId="getSchoolCourse",
 * tags={"frontend"},
 * @OA\Parameter(
*    name="Origin",
*    in="header",
*    description="Origin",
*    required=true,
*    example="http://example.com",
*    schema={
*    "type"="string"
*    },
*    style="simple",
* ),
 * @OA\Response(
 *    response=200,
 *    description="Success",
 *    @OA\JsonContent(
 *          @OA\Items(
 *               @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer", example=1),
 *               @OA\Property(property="price", type="integer", example=29),
 *               @OA\Property(property="teacher_id", type="integer", example=null),
 *               @OA\Property(property="category_id", type="integer", example=null),
 *               @OA\Property(property="program_id", type="integer", example=null),
 *               @OA\Property(property="locale_id", type="integer", example=7),
 *               @OA\Property(property="status_id", type="integer", example=null),
 *               @OA\Property(property="level", type="integer", example=null),
 *               @OA\Property(property="created_by", type="integer", example=null),
 *               @OA\Property(property="lessons", type="integer", example=10),
 *               @OA\Property(property="created_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *               @OA\Property(property="updated_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *               @OA\Property(property="currency", type="object",
 *                      @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer", example=1),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="symbol", type="string", example="KZT"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="name", type="string", example="Kazakhstani Tenge"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="symbol_native", type="string", example="тңг."),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="decimal_digits", type="integer", example=2),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="rounding", type="integer", example=0),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="code", type="string", example="KZT"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="name_plural", type="string", example="Kazakhstani Tenge"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="created_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="updated_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Property(property="course_locale", type="object",
 *                      @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer", example=1),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="locale_id", type="integer", example=1),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="name", type="string", example="new nm 2"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="image", type="string", example="dummy.png"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="description", type="string", example="course description"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="image_url", type="string", example="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/dummy.png"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="created_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="updated_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Property(property="author", type="object",
 *                      @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer", example=1),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="name", type="string", example="user 2"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="email", type="string", example="user@example.com"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="description", type="string", example="course description"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="profile_image", type="string", example="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/dummy.png"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="created_at", type="string", example="2021-03-31T23:20:09.000000Z"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="facebook_url", type="string", example="http://facebook.com"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="twitter_url", type="string", example="http://twitter.com"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="instagram_url", type="string", example="http://instagram.com"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="status", type="string", example="Active"),
 *               ),
 *       ),
 *   ),
 * ),
 * )
 */
```

Below is my default controller annotation

```
/**
* @OA\Info(title="API Documentation", version="1.0")
* @OA\Schemes(format="http")
* @OA\SecurityScheme(
*      securityScheme="bearerAuth",
*      in="header",
*      name="bearerAuth",
*      type="http",
*      scheme="bearer",
*      bearerFormat="JWT",
* )
*/
```

I also noticed that when we add "Origin", it is showing in the CURL preview but its not adding in API request header.

[image]

Can someone please guide me on what I'm missing here?